# Could not compile command - package does not exist

Tags: spring-boot, crash

I created very simple crash command

```
@Usage("Echo")
public class echo extends BaseCommand {

    @Command
    @Usage("Echo")
    public String main() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        InvocationContextImpl ctx = (InvocationContextImpl) context;
        return ctx.readLine("Msg: ", true);
    }
}
```

And it works fine. But when I add very simple pojo class

```
package sth;

public class Echo {

    private String echo;

    public String getEcho() {
        return echo;
    }

    public void setEcho(String echo) {
        this.echo = echo;
    }
}
```

My command:

```
    InvocationContextImpl ctx = (InvocationContextImpl) context;
    String msg = ctx.readLine("Msg: ", true);

    Echo echo = new Echo();
    echo.setEcho(msg);

    return echo.getEcho();
```

It works only when I run this from Idea. When I compile and run

```
    mvn clean install
    java -jar target/testproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

this this give me an error:

```
    org.crsh.shell.impl.command.spi.CommandException: Could not compile command
at 
    ...
    Caused by: org.crsh.lang.impl.java.CompilationFailureException: package sth does not exist
    cannot find symbol
      symbol:   class Echo
      location: class crash.commands.echo
    cannot find symbol
      symbol:   class Echo
      location: class crash.commands.echo
```

But when I run this from Idea everything works fine.

Comment: is the package `sth` correct?  Maybe you have another project in your IDE workspace where another `Echo` class is in?

Comment: No, only one project

Comment: If you're using Spring Boot 1.4, it could be this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6384

Comment: I downgraded to 1.3.7.RELEASE. Works fine now.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem. Running it trough IntelliJ works fine, but as soon as I try to run it as a JAR it fails. I'm running version 1.4.1 RELEASE and are unable to downgrade. Did you find any solution, @Mateusz ?

Comment: Unfortunately no :( Maybe use 1.4.2?